# Material Science dataset with feature-dependent inputs

Tags: regression, dataset

I'm dealing with a material science/chemistry dataset where I have a bunch of duplicates inputs formulas corresponding to different values of a specific features like temperature. It looks something like this:

```
Formula           Temperature(K)         (Other features)         target
  NaO2                 280                                         7.5
  NaO2                 340                                         5.6
  ZnO                  370                     ...                 6.7
  LaCuO3               300                                         5.6
  ZnO                  278                                         6.8
```

of course, I want to perform a regression task here, my question is, how should I treat the inputs?
I would like to train some model that takes into account different temperature values for the same compound. All the other features, based on chemical properties will be of course the same for the duplicates compounds, while the only thing that will vary on the same compounds is the temperature..
Basically the target varies for the same compound based on the temperature.

Comment: What do you want to use to predict what?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at what we did in the [SIMDAVIS](https://rosaleny.shinyapps.io/simdavis_dashboard/) dataset (you are welcome to view/download the dataset in the "Data" tab of the dashboard). There we assigned a **sampleID** to each *sample*. Some judgment based on scientific insight was necessary to decide what it takes to consider that something is a different *sample*.

For us, the same crystallographic structure but at a different *concentration* (see below) was a different sample, and we treated this variable exactly like the others. Same as it appears that can happen in your case, for many chemical structures we had more than one row where all columns were identical except this one.

In our case, *concentration* meant that you can have a general structure where dysprosium and yttrium take the same position, so that part of the formula reads Dy_x Y_(1-x) to quantify how "concentrated" dysprosium is in a given solid solution based on yttrium. We included this variable because for us this *concentration* was expected to be related to our target variables (magnetic memory, broadly speaking). Additionally, there was never the situation where we had a very large number of concentrations for the same structure (in which case we would have had a problem of effectively overrepresenting this structure in our study). In your case, it looks like the same could be done with temperature.

While in our study the effect of this variable was not especially interesting, you can appreciate that for a certain target variable (the presence of magnetic hysteresis) only for the value "Full hysteresis" do we find over 25% of the data points presenting less than 100% concentration, whereas there are barely any non-100% data points for the "No hysteresis" behavior:[image: Concentration of the magnetic metal ion for different magnetic hysteresis behaviors]
Figure 1: Concentration of the magnetic metal ion for different magnetic hysteresis behaviors. Obtained from [SIMDAVIS](https://rosaleny.shinyapps.io/simdavis_dashboard) [Duan, Y., et al. Data mining, dashboard and statistical analysis: a powerful framework for the chemical design of molecular nanomagnets. Preprint at https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.03199 (2021).].